# Setting error log filename in apache to include current date

Tags: apache, logging, apache-config

I'm trying to have apache create a new error log file every day, based on the current date.
The default error log filename is something like this:
ErrorLog "/logs/error.log"

and I want it to be something like:
ErrorLog "/logs/error_$year$month$day.log"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Cronolog](http://cronolog.org/)

> cronolog is a simple filter program
>   that reads log file entries from
>   standard input and writes each entry
>   to the output file specified by a
>   filename template and the current date
>   and time. When the expanded filename
>   changes, the current file is closed
>   and a new one opened. cronolog is
>   intended to be used in conjunction
>   with a Web server, such as Apache, to
>   split the access log into daily or
>   monthly logs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this approach. I read meanwhile in the apache.org docs that this probably is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to configure **logrotate** for apache to rotate apache's logs once per day then ..

For a Custom log having date information on every log line instead:

```
%...{format}t:  The time, in the form given by format, which should
                be in strftime(3) format. (potentially localized)
```

You have to use the strftime (man 3 strftime) formatting rules:

```
%F or its equivalent without dashes %Y%m%d
```

So:

```
# CustomLog with explicit format string
CustomLog my_log "%{%Y%m%d}t %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
```

Where **%{%Y%m%d}t** does the job

Comment: Does this timestamp the filename, or the actual message logged ?

Comment: Sorry, my answer is not on topic ... 

I misunderstood ... My approach would be to configure logrotate for apache to rotate apache's logs once per day then ... sorry again

Comment: Not a problem. I just wanted to clarify, however. You might want to edit your answer re. your logrotate answer, though

Answer (score 0):

Change to this in your httpd.conf

```
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs /var/logs/errorlog.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 5M"
```

This configuration will rotate the error logfile whenever it reaches a size of 5 megabytes, and the suffix to the logfile name will be created of the form errorlog.YYYY-mm-dd-HH_MM_SS.